# Show keyboard layout image in Kubuntu

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, keyboard-layout, input-language

In Gnome and maybe other desktops one can see details of the selected keyboard so that the way in which one has to type specific / special characters becomes obvious.

[image]

[image]

Is there a similar feature in Kubuntu?

(I don't mean onscreen keyboard, but the image of the keyboard, with all details of 2nd,  3rd and 4th [levels](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/655915/341192) to type special characters etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/697974/341192) answer, I had initially posted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/707476/341192) as a workaround. As there doesn't seem to be any Kubuntu or  Plasma-specific solution, I am posting it here anyway.

A launcher can be used with a command. First installing the needed package:

```
sudo apt install gkbd-capplet
```

Looking up the help of `gkbd-keyboard-display` there isn't a way to show the already selected layout, we have to specify the layout name or its order number:

```
gkbd-keyboard-display --help
Application Options:
  -g, --group=group number (1, 2, 3, 4)           Group to display
  -l, --layout=layout (with optional variant)     Layout to display
```

Be sure to disable the option "spare layouts" in settings if you want to use this for more than 3 layouts.

[image]

In order to show my Romanian layout, I have created the file `~/.local/share/applications/show-keyboard-layout_ro.desktop` with these contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Show keyboard layout ROMANIAN
Comment=
Icon=/home/cip/.icons/RO-Romania-Flag-icon.png
Exec=gkbd-keyboard-display -g 4
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility
```

`4` stands for the fact that Romanian is 4th in that list. Different ones can be created.

To launch it I type in the applications launcher:

[image]

And it pops up:

[image]